# unable to found rainbow method in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` 2.2.3 here is my code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
"""Plot out the different clusters"""

# Choose a different colour for each cluster
colour = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(centroids)))
```

It will throw unable to find `rainbow` reference

Comment: It is a problem of `matplotlib`, it is not `numpy`. can you put that `matplotlib` check you're using?

Comment: Try `plt.get_cmap('rainbow')`.

Comment: Matplotlib 2.2.3 definitely provides the `matplotlib.cm` within pyplot, hence `plt.cm.rainbow` will be available. If it doesn't work for you, maybe you have unintentionally overwritten something.